# Protractor: Zoom out

Tags: javascript, selenium, protractor

I am using protractor and need to zoom out to 50%, I have tried solutions from several other questions posted on StackOverflow but nothing has worked. Some of them include:

```
browser.actions().keyDown(protractor.Key.COMMAND).sendKeys(protractor.Key.SUBTRACT).keyUp(protractor.Key.CONTROL).perform();
browser.executeScript("document.body.style.zoom='50%'");
browser.executeScript("document.body.style.zoom='0.5'");
```

The .keyDown in the first solution says it's an unresolved function which I thought was strange (but there are other places in the code that gives me that error and works fine). Any ideas on what else I could try?

Comment: which browser are you trying this on ..  I just checked on chrome and this - `browser.executeScript("document.body.style.zoom='50%'")` and its working as expected

Comment: I am using Chrome on a Mac, weird that it's working for you and not me I will double check today

Comment: I tried that statement in my protractor.base.conf file as well as within the spec file itself and both did not work. If anyone has any other suggestions please let me know

Comment: Can you please check if you are using a get() after zooming in. I have stated the same in the answer below. Also if you can update the question with the location where you are triggering the zoom from, it can help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From my experience on working with zooming through Protractor I have seen that the `browser.executeScript()` to zoom doesnt work if there is a `browser.get()` after zooming in. I dont know why but thats how it works :)

This will not work -

```
browser.executeScript("document.body.style.zoom='50%'");
browser.get('http://www.protractortest.org/#/')
```

This will work

```
browser.get('http://www.protractortest.org/#/')
browser.executeScript("document.body.style.zoom='50%'");
```

This will not work -

```
onPrepare(){
    browser.executeScript("document.body.style.zoom='50%'");
}
```

The statement to zoom should be only in spec file and after all get() and navigate().

Comment: You're correct, thanks. It seems like the only answer is to copy and paste that in a lot of places (over 100 in my case), any ideas on a more efficient way rather than pasting the working line of code after every browser.get() ?

Comment: Hmm... didn't work for me. Not sure if this is outdated?